# Do you need public-transportation when public-issues already exists?

Tags: discussion, tags

This site has [public-transportation](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transportation) and [public-issues](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-issues). Yes, transportation is a subset of public issues. No, both tags are not necessary. Either remove [public-issues](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-issues) in favor of more specific tags such as public transportation, or remove public transportation in favor of more general tags like public issues.

Answer (score 3):

I actually see them as not overlapping at all.

[public-issues](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-issues) comes across to me as those sorts of awkward things that of course have to happen in public. Like spilling your stuff everywhere in the middle of a crowded mall, or your stomach growling (loudly, at a quiet moment) in class.

[public-transportation](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transportation) comes across as issues to do with, you know, *public transportation* (aptly named tag). Public issues can happen on public transportation, but public issues can also happen in a classroom, in the middle of the mall, or on an alien starship (does that qualify as public transportation?).

### Tl;dr, keep both.